# Choosing app that can send text (Whatsapp,Viber and default sms app) Android

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, android-package-managers

I have solution that works properly on Samsung devices but on Xiaomi devices Whatsapp starts automatically. I want that user chooses from which app to send some provided text.

This code is properly populating text field when user chooses contact but problem with Xiaomi still remains.

```
try {
                if (isAppInstalled(context, "com.whatsapp") && isAppInstalled(context,"com.viber.voip")) {
                    // Create intents for sending SMS, WhatsApp, and Viber
                    val smsIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                        .setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms")
                        .setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"))
                        .putExtra("sms_body", text)

                   val whatsappIntent = Intent().apply {
                        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)
                        type = "text/plain"
                        setPackage("com.whatsapp")
                    }

                    val viberIntent = Intent().apply {
                        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)
                        type = "text/plain"
                        setPackage("com.viber.voip")
                    }

                    // Create a list of Intent objects
                    val intentList = listOf(smsIntent,whatsappIntent, viberIntent)

                    // Check if there are any apps that can handle the given intents
                    val filteredIntentList = intentList.filter { intent ->
                        try {
                            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
                                intent,
                                PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY.toLong())
                            ).isNotEmpty()
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            // Handle exceptions that may occur during querying activities
                            false
                        }
                    }.distinctBy { it.`package`}

                    if (filteredIntentList.isNotEmpty()) {
                        // Create a chooser intent
                        val chooserIntent =
                            Intent.createChooser(filteredIntentList.first(), "Choose a messaging app")
                        chooserIntent.putExtra(
                            Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                            filteredIntentList.subList(1, filteredIntentList.size).toTypedArray()
                        )

                        // Start the activity
                        context.startActivity(chooserIntent)
                    } else {
                        // Handle the case when no apps can handle the given intents
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                // Handle any exceptions that may occur during the process
            }
```

I also add this to manifest:

```
   <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent>
     //   <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
        <package android:name="com.viber.voip" />
        <package android:name="com.android.mms" />
    </queries>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me and my team we had the same problem, however Xiaomi devices due to their customized MIUI Rom might sometimes behave differently.

```
try {
    val text = "Your message here"

    val smsIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
        .setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"))
        .putExtra("sms_body", text)

    val whatsappIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)
        .type = "text/plain"

    whatsappIntent.`package` = "com.whatsapp"

    val viberIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)
        .type = "text/plain"

    viberIntent.`package` = "com.viber.voip"

    val intentList = listOf(smsIntent, whatsappIntent, viberIntent)

    // Filter out intents that can't be handled
    val filteredIntentList = intentList.filter { intent ->
        try {
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
                intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
            ).isNotEmpty()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Handle exceptions that may occur during querying activities
            false
        }
    }.distinctBy { it.`package` }

    if (filteredIntentList.isNotEmpty()) {
        // Create a chooser intent
        val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(filteredIntentList.first(), "Choose a messaging app")
        chooserIntent.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
            filteredIntentList.subList(1, filteredIntentList.size).toTypedArray()
        )

        // Start the activity
        startActivity(chooserIntent)
    } else {
        // Handle the case when no apps can handle the given intents
        // Show a message to the user or take alternative action
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    // Handle any exceptions that may occur during the process
}
```

Please also note:
maybe it wont solve your issue with Xiaomi devices, probably you will need to read **(manufacturer-specific documentation) on how to handle implicit intents**

Comment: This is working but i got 2 Whatsapp app shown (there should be only 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass with any type of app using below code:

```
    val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  "Send Some Text")
    shareIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or 
    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
    shareIntent.type = "text/*"
    val chooser = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..")
    startActivity(chooser)
```